# How hide blur for UIPopoverPresentationController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I've implemented popover for UIButton:

```
    @objc func showList(sender: AnyObject?) {

        guard let buttonView = sender?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIButton else { return }
        guard let popVC = R.storyboard.first.VC() else { return }
        popVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        let popOverVC = popVC.popoverPresentationController
        popOverVC?.delegate = self
        popOverVC?.sourceView = buttonView
        popOverVC?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 190, width: 0, height: 0)
        popOverVC?.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)

        popVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 150, height: 250)

        showedViewController.present(popVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


extension VCInteractor: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return .none
    }
}
```

It's working good, but I need one fix - I want to hide `UIVisualEffectBackdropView` for my popover (it's like blur under my UITableViewController). So, I can't find any info how to disable (hide) this blur, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried looking into:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle

Also I suppose you want to block interaction with the background VC (maybe you can have a different presenation style (eg add child view controller and disable user interaction) 
or  you can use a snapshot and use it as a background. 
....
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        layer.render(in: context)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenshot
...

Comment: As implied by the above comment - it likely gets down to (1) view hierarchy and (2) understanding that most *canned* "visual effect views" work within the hierarchy and contain content views. If you need to go "deeper", consider replacing what `UIKit` does automagically/automatically with CoreImage.

Answer (score 6):

I've fixed my issue with my custom class

```
class PopoverBackgroundView: UIPopoverBackgroundView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override static func contentViewInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }

    override static func arrowHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    override var arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection {
        get { return UIPopoverArrowDirection.down }
        set {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    override var arrowOffset: CGFloat {
        get { return 0 }
        set {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```

and I've added it like that

```
popOverVC?.popoverBackgroundViewClass = PopoverBackgroundView.self
```

that's all

Answer (score 2):

here i have a very simple solution.

```
    let appearance = UIVisualEffectView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [NSClassFromString("_UIPopoverStandardChromeView")! as! UIAppearanceContainer.Type])
    appearance.effect = UIVisualEffect()
```

add the code to the AppDelegate.swift file or anywhere the app is getting initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding this to the PopoverBackgroundView that Vadim Nikolaev has posted above. This removes the "clear halo" effect when removing the blur.

```
`override func didMoveToWindow() {
         super.didMoveToWindow()
         if #available(iOS 13, *) {
             // iOS 13 (or newer)
             if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
                 let transitionViews = window.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "UITransitionView" }
                 for transitionView in transitionViews {
                     let shadowView = transitionView.subviews.filter { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UICutoutShadowView" }.first
                     shadowView?.isHidden = true
                 }
             }
         }
     }`
```